# MYSQL Stored Procedure list of string parameter and using IN clause

Tags: mysql, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure query. I'm using this code in my vb.net in dataset so i need is to pass parameter in my every where clause. or can i pass my whole where clause in this stored procedure from my vb.net.If not how can i do the "where IN clause" because im getting error if I'm call my stored procedure.

Maybe someone can give me some idea how can i handle this problem.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `lcs_rdb`.`sp_MissedCallsReport`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_MissedCallsReport`()
BEGIN
    select
    cdr_extension_no, cdr_charge_to, COUNT(cdr_call_type_code) as answered, 
    SUM(cdr_call_type_code = 'BSY') as Busy,
    sum(cdr_call_type_code = 'ABN') as abandon, 
    sum(cdr_call_type_code in ('BSY','ABN')) as total,
    coalesce((sum(case cdr_call_type_code when 'ABN' then cdr_duration_number/60000 else 0 end) / sum(cdr_call_type_code = 'ABN')),0) as avg_abandon,
    coalesce((sum(cdr_call_type_code in ('BSY','ABN')) / 
    (sum(cdr_call_type_code in ('BSY','ABN')) + COUNT(cdr_call_type_code))) *100,0) as missed_calls_rate
    from cdr_departments 
        where cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND 
    cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{1}' AND '{2}' 
    AND cdr_call_class_id IN({3}) AND cdr_call_type_id IN({4}) 
    AND cdr_extension_id IN({5}) or cdr_route_member_id IN ({6})
GROUP BY cdr_extension_no;
    END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `IN` parameters for your stored procedure to use with `WHERE` clause.

**Example**:

```
PROCEDURE `sp_MissedCallsReport`(
   IN param_cdr_site_id INT
 , IN param_cdr_datetime_min DATETIME
 , IN param_cdr_datetime_max DATETIME
 , IN param_cdr_call_class_id_csv VARCHAR(1024) -- csv integers
 , IN param_cdr_call_type_id_csv VARCHAR(1024) -- csv integers
 , IN param_cdr_extension_id_csv VARCHAR(1024) -- csv integers
 , IN param_cdr_route_member_id_csv VARCHAR(1024) -- csv integers
)
```

I suggest CSV form of `int` valuess as `varchar` params for parameter placeholder numbers 3,4,5, and 6. It is because, you want to use them with `IN` as a set to search in them. As we can't pass an array of values as procedure parameters, we can make use of CSV form as an alternative. 
And as the input is in CSV format, the `IN` is not suitable to use for search.
We can use `FIND_IN_SET` with CSV values.

**Example**: (for your `where` clause):

```
where cdr_site_id = param_cdr_site_id
  AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN param_cdr_datetime_min AND param_cdr_datetime_max 
  AND FIND_IN_SET( cdr_call_class_id, param_cdr_call_class_id_csv ) 
  AND FIND_IN_SET( cdr_call_type_id, param_cdr_call_type_id_csv ) 
  AND (    FIND_IN_SET( cdr_extension_id, param_cdr_extension_id_csv ) 
        or FIND_IN_SET ( cdr_route_member_id, param_cdr_route_member_id_csv ) )
```

**Refer to**:

- [***CREATE PROCEDURE Syntax***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)
- [***FIND_IN_SET( str, strlist )***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)